# asp.net mvc code first. make dropdown required

Tags: entity-framework, attributes, code-first, required

Below is my class

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Unit of measure1 is required.")]
    public int Uom1Id { get; set; }
    public UnitOfMeasure Uom1 { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Unit of measure2 is required.")]
    public int Uom2Id { get; set; }
    public UnitOfMeasure Uom2{ get; set; }
}

public class UnitOfMeasure
{
    public int UnitOfMeasureID { get; set; }
    public string MeasureName { get; set; }
}
```

My initializer below:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasRequired(x => x.StockUnitOfMeasure)
       .WithMany()
       .HasForeignKey(x => x.StockUnitOfMeasureId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().HasRequired(x => x.PurchaseUnitOfMeasure)
           .WithMany()
           .HasForeignKey(x => x.PurchaseUnitOfMeasureId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    }
```

Create code:

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Uom1Id, "Stock Unit Of Measure")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Uom1Id", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Uom1Id )
    </div>
```

Im new to EF, I dont know why the attribute [Required] does not work for the field Uom1Id and Uom2Id, but it works with other fields in my other classes.

> The ViewData item that has the key 'Uom1Id' is of
>   type 'System.Int32'     but must be of type
>   'IEnumerable'.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`int` can not be null because it is a valuable type, so there is no need to add the `Required` attribute to `Uom1Id` and `Uom2Id`. For UI you may create a viewmodel in which `Uom1Id` and `Uom2Id` will be `int?` (nullable).

Comment: thanks Andrei, Im getting an error upon hitting the create button if the two dropdowns were blank. How am I going to make the dropdown required? thanks